# Magento 2 : Getting error in adding product grid using ui component

Tags: magento2, error, product-grid

Added product grid using ui component, but getting an error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

What is the meaning of this code in templates/modulename/edit/assign_products.phtml

```
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

Comment: check the devdocs to see how to require JS functionality http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html